# Splitting a string with a certain pattern in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am writing a parser for a file containing the following string pattern:

```
Key : value
Key : value
Key : value
etc...
```

I am able to retrieve those lines one by one into a list. What I would like to do is to separate the key from the value for each one of those strings. I know there is the `split()` method that can take a Regex and do this for me, but I am very unfamiliar with them so I don't know what Regex to give as a parameter to the `split()` function.

Also, while not in the specifications of the file I am parsing, I would like for that Regex to be able to recognize the following patterns as well (if possible):

```
Key: value
Key :value
Key:value
etc...
```

So basically, whether there's a space or not after/before/after AND before the `:` character, I would like for that Regex to be able to detect it. What is the Regex that can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In other words `split` method should look for `:` and zero or more whitespaces before or after it.

```
Key: value
   ^^
Key :value
   ^^
Key:value
   ^
Key : value
   ^^^
```

In that case `split("\\s*:\\s*")` should do the trick.

Explanation:

- `\\s` represents any whitespace
- `*` means one or more occurrences of element described before it
- `\\s*` means zero or more whitespaces.

---

On the other hand you may want also to find entire `key:value` pair and place parts matching `key` and `value` in separate groups (you can even name groups as you like using `(?<groupName>regex)`). In that case you may use

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<key>\\w+)\\s*:\\s*(?<value>\\w+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourData);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println("key = " + m.group("key"));
    System.out.println("value = " + m.group("value"));
    System.out.println("--------");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `String.split()`, you could use this:

```
String input = "key : value";
String[] s = input.split("\\s*:\\s*");
String key = s[0];
String value = s[1];
```

This will split the String at the ":", but add all whitespaces in front of the ":" to it, so that you will receive a trimmed string.

Explanation:

- `\\s*` will match any whitespace, by default this is equal to `[ \\n\\r\\t]*`
- The `:` in between the two `\\s*` means that your : need to be there

Note that this solution will cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if your input line does not contain the key-value-format as you defined it.

If you are not sure if the line really contain the key-value-String, maybe because you want to have an empty line at the end of your file like there normally is, you could do it like that:

```
String input = "key : value";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\S+)\\s*:\\s*(.+)").matcher(input);
if (m.matches())
{
    String key = m.group(1); // note that the count starts by 1 here
    String value = m.group(2);
}
```

Explanation:

- `\\S+` matches any non-whitespace String - if it contains whitespaces, the next part of the regex will be matches with this expression already. Note that the () around it mark so that you can get it's value by `m.group()`.
- `\\s*` will match any whitespace, by default this is equal to `[ \\n\\r\\t]*`
- The `:` in between the two `\\s*` means that your : need to be there
- The last group, `.+`, will match any string, containing whitespaces and so on.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the split method but can pass delimiter as ":"

This splits the string when it sees ':', then you can trim the values to get the key and value.

```
String s = "   keys : value   ";
String keyValuePairs[] = s.split(":");
String key = keyValuePairs[0].trim();
String value = keyValuePairs[1].trim();
```

You can also make use of regex to simplify it.

```
String keyValuePairs[] = s.trim().split("[ ]*:[ ]*");
```

s.trim() will remove the spaces before and after the string (if you have it in your case), So sting will become "keys : value" and

```
[ ]*:[ ]*
```

to split the string with regular expression saying spaces (one or more) : spaces (one or more) as delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

For a pure regex solution, you can use the following pattern (note the space at the beginning):

```
 ?: ?
```

See http://regexr.com/39evh

Comment: Why do you use a '?' instead of a '*'? Do you only want zero or one ' ' to be matched?

Comment: That really depends on the details of the problem - if more than one space can exist, * is the to use.

Comment: But '*' will match everything that was matched with '?', so I don't see any reason to use '?' in this case

Answer (score -1):

```
 String[] tokensVal = str.split(":");
 String key = tokensVal[0].trim();
 String value = tokensVal[1].trim();
```

Comment: This won't compile, you can't redefine the local variable `key`.

Comment: But the OP can't learn from undocumented and uncompilable (before _Pshemo_ edited your answer) code